# Debian reinstall libjpeg62 without remove many packages

Tags: linux, debian, reinstall, apt

my package libjpeg62 is currently not working and if I want to reinstall, apt want to remove 539 packages :

```
clement@pc2:~$ sudo apt install libjpeg62 --reinstall
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets suivants ont été installés automatiquement et ne sont plus nécessaires :
  apt-transport-https ca-certificates-mono cabextract cli-common filezilla-common fonts-sil-gentium  
  [...] 
  x11proto-scrnsaver-dev x11proto-video-dev xinit xorg
Veuillez utiliser « apt-get autoremove » pour les supprimer.
Les paquets supplémentaires suivants seront installés : 
  foomatic-filters libgpod4-nogtk pinentry-curses
Paquets suggérés :
  pinentry-doc
Paquets recommandés :
  ghostscript cups enscript a2ps mpage poppler-utils colord libgpod-common
Les paquets suivants seront ENLEVÉS :
  adwaita-icon-theme aisleriot alacarte analog arc-theme argyll baobab bijiben brasero brasero-cdrkit caribou caribou-antler cheese
  [...]
  transmission-gtk unoconv vinagre vino virtualbox-5.0 vlc vlc-nox xboard xdg-user-dirs-gtk xmind yelp zeitgeist zeitgeist-datahub
  zenity
Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  foomatic-filters libgpod4-nogtk libjpeg62 pinentry-curses
0 mis à jour, 4 nouvellement installés, 539 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 431 ko dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 3 077 Mo d'espace disque seront libérés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n]
```

Sorry, my apt is in french. 
How can I keep all my packages and reinstall libjpeg62 ?

**Update:** Here is the output of `# apt-cache policy libjpeg62`:

```
clement@pc2:~$ sudo apt-cache policy libjpeg62
libjpeg62:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6b1-3+deb7u1
  Version table:
     6b1-3+deb7u1 0
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Could you update your post with the output of `# apt-cache policy libjpeg62` ? It *appears* that you have some external repositories added and the version of the `libjpeg62` package about to be installed is somehow different from that those 539 packages depend on. It's just a guess but worth verifying.

Comment: On a side note, making your command-line programs output English for the purpose of posting to support forums [is easy](http://superuser.com/a/571055/130459).